# What are the advantage and disadvantages of right justified I2S mode over Left justified I2S mode and Basic I2S mode?

Tags: audio, hardware, serial-communication

I2S specifications provide different modes of operation. I tried looking for advantages of one mode over the other but could not find any good literature. Can anyone provide or explain the advantage of one mode over the other ?

Answer (score 3):

With samples that are aligned to the most significant bit, the sample length does not matter (because if the sent and expected sample lengths differ, any ignored or read-as-zero bits are the LSBs).

Otherwise, all choices are arbitrary and do not have any advantage whatsoever over each other.
(This is why hardware designers choose one I²S mode at random, instead of selecting an obviously best mode.)

Comment: Just as a doubt to clear, right justified mode, one can stuff the bits in the signal before actual data. This will help in sending sync words, or crc checks, isn't it ?

Comment: What is the difference between "bits" and "actual data"?

Comment: crc checks is incorrect example, but by bits I mean some sync information which can be sent only in first frame and data mean pcm data over i2s bus.

Comment: I²S does not have sync information on the data line.